# Insert data using Store Procedures

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, insert

[image: table]

Let's say after I had login I will be prompt to enter the Name and address how do I insert data  with at least 2 table linking to each other using Store procedures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.user_Add(
 @username VARCHAR(50),
 @password NVARCHAR(50)
) 
AS 
BEGIN
   -- username should be unique
   IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Login WHERE username = @username) BEGIN
      INSERT INTO Login (username, password)
      VALUES (@username, @password)

      RETURN @@IDENTITY
   END
   ELSE BEGIN
   -- already taken username should be handled somehow
      RETURN 0
   END
END

CREATE PROC dbo.user_StudentAdd(
  @loginID INT,
  @name NVARCHAR(50),
  @addr NVARCHAR(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
  -- add new record for new student 
  -- probably before you should check if student is not already exist
  INSERT INTO Student (LoginID, [Student Name], [Student address])
  VALUES (@loginID, @name, @addr)

  -- returns new StudentID, you can also use `RETURN` to return StudentId (if you need it)
  SELECT @@IDENTITY
END
```

As your homework you can write a third stored procedure which calls two above
and use result from first one in second one. Hint -- use `EXEC` to assign value returned by
stored procedure (here are details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx).

I didn't test it, so it can fails due to misspelling.
Also I've never used columns with space inside so I am not sure how to handle them.

I **assume** that:

1. User (record in `login` table) already exists and value of `login.loginID` is accessible (user has already logged-in).
2. It was checked that logged-in user needs to fulfill his students data.

One **more thing** -- I would not use column names with space (or non-Latin characters).

Comment: I got an error `"Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints."` after trying to add a new student, here are my codes:

`StudentTableAdapter.user_StudentAdd(LibraryDataSet.Student, LoginIDTextBox.Text, Student_NameTextBox.Text, Student_addressTextBox.Text)`

I'm not sure on what went wrong here.

Comment: No idea what is wrong, but I would start at checking table definitions for foreign keys (if FKs are defined correctly).